# How to set HTTP status code using identifier in linkerd plugins

Tags: linkerd

I am using linkerD to set up an authorization plugin, in Java. Currently I am using an Identifier to intercept the request & check if the user is authorized. (Using : https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd-examples/tree/master/plugins/header-classifier as an example)

If the user is not authorized, the request should not reach the backend service. I am throwing a runtime exception in such cases (do let me know if there is another way for preventing the request to reach the backend). Linkerd sends the response as 502 Bad Gateway. Linkerd should have a mechanism by which I can specify the HTTP status code I want to send back.

I tried using a responseClassifier along with the identifier, but it looks like the responseClassifier does not get invoked when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to send back custom response codes from an identifier plugin, based on the comments on [this issue](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd/issues/1465):

> This is a limitation of using the identifier plugin interface for authorization. If you prefer, you can return an UnidentifiedRequest exception which will return a 400 Bad Request. In the long term we'd like to add a new plugin interface specifically for authorization which would allow more control over the error responses.

But linkerd is planning on adding [better support for authorization plugins](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd/issues/1466) in a future release.